# Log4JavaScript server-side coding

Tags: javascript, log4javascript

I'm trying to use **Log4Javascript** for logging logs from JavaScript to a file. I'm using the `AjaxAppender` to try to send the data to the server. But whenever i am trying to log the file specified in url field is empty

```
url = "demo.log";
var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender(url);
```

As it is a **POST request** I can see in firebug that the data is sent as parameter. But how can the logs be saved in demo.log For each logger a new request is sent.

How can we append the logs in log file. I am new to Log4Javascript. Can anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old, but i want to give at least a short answer:

At first we take a look at the docs for the AjaxAppender of log4javascript:

> A flexible appender that asynchronously sends log messages to a server
>   via HTTP.

So, what you need is a server that is capable of handling your POST-Request.
Whether you like to write a small server in JavaScript based on nodejs or a Java-Server or ... is your choice.
But you need a server. And the server decides what to do with those messages, e.g. logging them to a file.

A possible JavaScript solution could be based on nodejs, express and log4js